# Equitably allocating liquid across multiple uneven sized tanks

Tags: optimization, packing-problem

Is there a mathematical technique - ideally linear optimisation - for the following.

I have a volume of liquid that I want to allocate equitably across multiple tanks. The volume added to each tank should be equal until the smallest tank is full or the initial volume is exhausted. Then the remaining tanks should be filled with equal volumes until each tank is filled in order of size or the initial volume is exhausted.

I've looked at water filling (often used in communication channel allocation) and bin packing algorithms.

Comment: Suppose the volumes of the tanks in increasing order are $V_1\le V_2\le\dots\le V_n$. Consider the function $V(v)=\sum_i \min(v,V_i)$, which gives the total volume used if you try to fill $v$ volume in each tank.

Comment: Thanks for that, Rahul. I think that means I'll end up with some constraints that use the min function but I can have a crack at linearising those constraints. I'll start with an objective function minimising the residual from the available allocation with other constraints on total allocated etc

Comment: Since $V(v)$ is monotonically increasing in $v$, you could simply use binary search on $i$ to bracket the solution $v\in[V_i,V_{i+1}]$.